# Missing WinMain() arguments in Windows SDK sample

Tags: visual-c++, winapi, winmain

In one of the samples that come w/ Windows SDK (the CreateProcessVerb sample), the WinMain code is as follows:

```
int APIENTRY
wWinMain (HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, PWSTR pszCmdLine, int)
{
..
```

Note that only the 3rd argument is actually specified, the rest have been ignored.  How is this possible?  Why does the C++ compiler not get upset w/ this?  Are default values being pulled in, and if so, through what mechanism?

Thanks -

Todd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++ you don't have to give names to the parameters you don't use.  In C you can do that only with prototypes:

```
void function(int, char *, double, long);
```

In C++ this also works in definitions:

```
void function(int, char *, double, long)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you Dmitry.  Marked as answer, +1.